# Sort Rows into new sheets based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Preamble: I'm a self taught hand at anything VB script. Most of my stuff is hodgepodged-together scripts I've found.

I need to sort rows into different sheets based on a set of cell values.
In some instances its a set of numbers which would apply, in others it's a very direct value.

See: 
A cell value of 1-99  goes to a sheet titled "1-99"
A cell value of 100 goes to a sheet titled "100"

There are several ranges like that. The working iteration I have only works for the direct value.
Basically, how to I get the script to understand less than or greater than or both--for instances in which it's between sets (see: 101-199)?

```
Set Sorter = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("M2:M100000")
For Each cell In Sorter

If cell.Value = "100" Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("100").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).PasteSpecial
If cell.Value = "200" Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("200").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).PasteSpecial
End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Thank you for any and all help.

EDIT:

Below are the ranges: 
1-99
100
101-199
200
201-299
300

Comment: which column has the value to evaluate?  M? or C?  Also, could you be very specific as to where you wish to copy the data?  It looks like you are copying the entire row, but attempting to paste from only Column C.  I'm assuming what you are trying to do is take all the RAW DATA and check a value in (M??) and if it (etc) move to Sheet named the same as it's value range.

Comment: PJ, you are correct. It's M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution for you that should show you some good concepts in VBA.

**PREP FROM YOU:**

Create sheets named "1-99", "100", "101-199", "200", "201-299", "300"

Include the header rows, the code I wrote works from row 2, so if your headers take up more than that, you will simply have to modify the initialization part.

Copy this code into a module and run it.

**PROCESS:**

Initialize the row numbers and names of all the sheets

Loop through "Raw Data" and get the tempValue to evaluate.

Using SELECT CASE statements, decide which rows go to which sheets.

Pass some arguments into a sub that will move the data accordingly, saving space and sanity.

**NOTE:**  I'm unsure of your column that has the value to check, It looked like "M" so that's what I'm using.  If it's "A" you can change it, and let me know, I will modify the answer.

**TESTED:**

```
Sub SortValuesToSheets()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim tempValue As Double         'Using Double not knowing what kind of numbers you are evaluating
Dim lRow As Long

Dim sh1 As String, sh2 As String, sh3 As String
Dim sh4 As String, sh5 As String, sh6 As String
Dim raw As String

Dim sh1Row As Long, sh2Row As Long, sh3Row As Long
Dim sh4Row As Long, sh5Row As Long, sh6Row As Long

'INITIALIZE TARGET SHEETS
    'Name the target sheets
    raw = "Raw Data"
    sh1 = "1-99"
    sh2 = "100"
    sh3 = "101-199"
    sh4 = "200"
    sh5 = "201-299"
    sh6 = "300"

    'Set the row number for each target sheet to 2, to account for headers
    sh1Row = 2
    sh2Row = 2
    sh3Row = 2
    sh4Row = 2
    sh5Row = 2
    sh6Row = 2

    lastRow = Sheets(raw).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row           'Get the last Row
    lastCol = Sheets(raw).Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'and column

    'BEGIN LOOP THROUGH RAW DATA
    For lRow = 2 To lastRow
        tempValue = CDbl(Sheets(raw).Cells(lRow, "M").Value)        'set TempValue to SEARCH COLUMN

        Select Case tempValue
            Case Is < 1
                MsgBox ("Out of Range, Under 1")
            Case 1 To 99
                Call CopyTempRow(lRow, sh1, sh1Row, lastCol)
                sh1Row = sh1Row + 1
            Case 100
                Call CopyTempRow(lRow, sh2, sh2Row, lastCol)
                sh2Row = sh2Row + 1
            Case 101 - 199
                Call CopyTempRow(lRow, sh3, sh3Row, lastCol)
                sh3Row = sh3Row + 1
            Case 200
                Call CopyTempRow(lRow, sh4, sh4Row, lastCol)
                sh4Row = sh4Row + 1
            Case 201 - 299
                Call CopyTempRow(lRow, sh5, sh5Row, lastCol)
                sh5Row = sh5Row + 1
            Case 300
                Call CopyTempRow(lRow, sh6, sh6Row, lastCol)
                sh6Row = sh6Row + 1
            Case Is > 300
                MsgBox ("Out of Range, Over 300")
        End Select
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

This is the subroutine that will copy the entire row.  The reason for separating it is so that we don't have to re-write for each case with the slight variations.  You wouldn't want to see this loop 6 times with only one number being changed each time.  If you have to change it, you change it here, once, and call it whenever you need.

```
Sub CopyTempRow(row As Long, target As String, tRow As Long, lastCol As Long)

    For lCol = 1 To lastCol
        Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, lCol) = Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(row, lCol)
    Next lCol

End Sub
```

Comment: It is M. This works well, though I'm getting an error for temp value. Thank you for your in depth instruction!

Comment: what error?  let's get it to where you have the answer you need.

Comment: PJ, I figured out my error. My error was in some careless 'renaming' on my part (see: reaccomodating your code to what I later found out was my actual need). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Dim v, s

Set Sorter = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("M2:M100000")

For Each cell In Sorter
    v = cell.Value

    if Len(v) > 0 And Isnumeric(v) Then

        If v>1 and v<=99 Then
            s = "1-99"
        Elseif v = 100 Then
            s = "100"
        Else
            s = ""
        End If

        If s<>"" Then 
           Sheets(s).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Entirerow.Value = _
                            c.entirerow.Value
        End if
     End if       
Next
```